# Convert Promise object to JSON in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, angular2-http

I'm trying to make an HTTP POST and then check the response to see if it fails or succeeds.

The HTTP call looks like this :

```
doLogin(credentials) {
    var header = new Headers();
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    var body = 'username=' + credentials.username + '&password=' + credentials.password;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.post(this.url, body, {
            headers: header
        })
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    resolve(data.json());
                },
                error => {
                    resolve(error.json());
                }
            );
    });

}
```

And the call of this function is the following :

```
data: Object;
errorMessage: Object;

login($event, username, password) {
    this.credentials = {
        username: username,
        password: password
    };

    this._loginService.doLogin(this.credentials).then(
        result => {
            this.data = result;
            console.log(this.data);
        },
        error => {
            this.errorMessage = <any>error;
            console.log(this.errorMessage);
        });
}
```

On Chrome console, the data is the following :

```
Object {status: "Login success", token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJjcmlzdGkiLCJ1c2VyS…blf1AzZ6KzRWQFNGXCrIeUHRG3Wrk7ZfCou135WmbVa15iYTA"}
```

How can I access the status in Angular 2? Because if I'm trying to access `this.data.status`, it's not working.

Should I create a class with the status and token properties?

Comment: *Where* are you trying to access `this.data.status`? Inside the callback? Do you know what *"asynchronous"* means, or why you have to subscribe and provide the callbacks?

Comment: Can you try the following.  Change `result =>` to `(result:any) =>` . Then `console.log(this.data.status);`

Comment: What is not working? Is there an error message? You can create an interface no need for class.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have to use subscribe in order to have the http request completed, no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you can use the `response.ok`boolean that's available in the subscription of the observable from the http.

So based on your code you could pass the `data` object straight to the promise and inspect `data.ok` before parsing the `data.json`.

```
//...
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.post(this.url, body, {
        headers: header
    })
        .subscribe(resolve,
         error => {
                reject(error.json());
            }
        );
});

// then you would have something like this:

this._loginService.doLogin(this.credentials).then(
    result => {
        if (result.ok) {
            this.data = result;
            console.log(this.data);
        }
    },
    error => {
        this.errorMessage = <any>error;
        console.log(this.errorMessage);
    })
```

**SUGGESTION**

Now, I would recommend getting rid of the promise, as I believe you don't really need it. whoever is consuming your service can just subscribe to the observable returned by the http post, like so:

```
doLogin(credentials) {
    let header = new Headers();
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    var body = 'username='+credentials.username+'&password='+credentials.password;
    return this.http.post(this.url, body, { headers: header });
}
```

Then, when logging in:

```
login($event, username, password) {
    this.credentials = {
        username: username,
        password: password
    };

    this._loginService.doLogin(this.credentials).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.ok) { // <== CHECK Response status
            this.data = response.json();
            console.log(this.data);
        } else {
            // handle bad request
        }
    },
    error => {
        this.errorMessage = <any>error;
        console.log(this.errorMessage);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, this works, but how can I get my token from the data response ?

Comment: If you are using my suggested approach, you should be able to access it through `response.json()`, so something along the lines of `var token = this.data.token`. You can inspect the response object through the debugger.

Comment: I manage to access the token by creating an empty json with the same properties as response.json (). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
data: Object;
errorMessage: Object;

login($event, username, password) {
    this.credentials = {
        username: username,
        password: password
    };

    this._loginService.doLogin(this.credentials).then(
        (result: any) => {
            this.data = result;
            console.log(this.data);
            console.log(this.data.status);
        },
        error => {
            this.errorMessage = <any>error;
            console.log(this.errorMessage);
        });
}
```

Set the `result` to type any. That way you'll be able to access the `status`, however you could create a `class` and use `rxjs/map` within your `service` to populate the `class` if you so desire.

Comment: ERROR in /Users/cristi/licenta/onlinebanking-frontend/src/app/login/login.component.ts (41,39): Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Object'.)